# SASS / SCSS @extend rule selectors

Tags: css, sass

I'm having a little problem with the @extend rule, this is what I got (focus on the h1):

```
.content-header {
    // CSS properties
    h1 {
        // CSS properties
    }
}

.box-header {
    // CSS properties
    h1 {
        @extend .content-header h1; // My selector problem!
        // And his own CSS properties
    }
}
```

So it will be:

```
.content-header h1, .box-header h1 {
    /* Happily sharing the same CSS properties */
}
```

But it seems like `@extend` don't like that, is any other way to write this without giving the `h1` a class??

Answer (score 10):

Nested selectors cannot be extended - in fact, that's the syntax error that is reported by the parser. Structural comments aside (I can't think of a scenario where the above `@extend` relationship is warranted), this is not something that can be currently accomplished with SASS.

NB: this is, however supported by [Stylus](http://learnboost.github.com/stylus/docs/extend.html) if you're open to it.

Answer (score 6):

An obvious solution whould be to define a new `@mixin your-name` for your `.content-header h1` definitions and `@include your-name` within `.box-header h1`.

But, there is a much better solution [Referencing Parent Selectors: &](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#referencing_parent_selectors_) :

```
h1 {
    .content-header &,
    .box-header & {
        // CSS properties
    }
    .box-header & {
        // And his own CSS properties
    }
}
```

It's not obvious because the logic reverse but it's better to maintain. You are changing the definitions of `h1` for a specific selector.

Answer (score 1):

Nested @extend is not allowed. Try this for a work around

```
.foo {
  background-color: lime;    
}
.b{
  margin:0px;
}
.baz {
  @extend .foo;
  @extend .b;
}
```

Some thing I constructed for my personel use below sharing with you all, This dynamically constructs the selector, Since special characters are not allowed in naming conventions I used '--' to seperate class

```
$ih-classes: ( "module--cardContainer--header",
                "a"
              );
  %module--cardContainer--header {
    color: #1e1d1c;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 0.0714rem solid #e0dddc;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 3.1429rem;
    font-size: 1.2857rem;
    font-family: ProximaNovaSemiBold;
}
%a{
  color:red;
}

@function str-replace($string, $search, $replace: '') {
  $index: str-index($string, $search);

  @if $index {
    @return str-slice($string, 1, $index - 1) + $replace + str-replace(str-slice($string, $index + str-length($search)), $search, $replace);
  }

  @return $string;
}
@mixin generate-framework-code() {

              @each  $icon in $ih-classes {
               $val : str-replace($icon, '--', ' .');
                  .#{$val} {
                            @extend %#{$icon};
                         }
                  }
}

@include generate-framework-code();
```

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you can only extend a single class. Generally, nesting with extend should be skipped. There is more about extend and its options  in [this text](https://kolosek.com/css-extend/).